# The origin of sprintf-style string formatting

Tags: string, formatting, multilingual, printf

The string formatting concept found in **sprintf** can be found in almost any language today *(you know, smothering a string with %s %d %f etc. and providing a list of variables to fill their places)*.

**Which langugage was it originally that had a library function or language construct which offered this functionality?**

Please specify some kind of source reference to confirm your claim, so that we avoid pure speculation or guessing.

Regards

Robert

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipedia has a pretty thorough history.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf) It suggests that the C printf function had its origins in BCPL's writef function.

Comment: That article is more information than I ever needed to know about it. And a perfect example of why I love Wikipedia: You can find THE most obscure, interesting trivia EVER there ...

Answer (score 5):

I would say all of them trace their roots back to BCPL.  We used BCPL to do operating systems programming for the 6809 processor two decades ago and it had a `writef()` function which took arguments such as `%i2` (equivalent to C's `%2d`).

C was based on a cut-down version of BCPL and inherited a similar mechanism for formatting output and I'm pretty certain all other instances picked it up from C after that.

I could be wrong, it won't be the first or last time, but I'm pretty confident that's right, given what I know about the BCPL language and its origins.