# Why does %e behave different than %g in format strings?

Tags: python, c, format-specifiers

I have tried this in Python2, Python3 and C:

Why do these format string return numbers with different precision?

```
>>> "%.3e" % 123456789
'1.235e+08' 
>>> "%.3g" % 123456789
'1.23e+08'
```

Comment: Because they are different? After looking at the answers, I am puzzled as to why OP thinks two different format specs which behave as intended, but are different, should be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Python 3.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> `'e'`:
>
> Exponent notation. Prints the number in scientific notation using the letter ‘e’ to indicate the exponent. The default precision is `6`.
>
> `'g'`:
>
> General format. For a given precision `p >= 1`, this rounds the number to p significant digits and then formats the result in either fixed-point format or in scientific notation, depending on its magnitude.
>
> The precise rules are as follows: suppose that the result formatted with presentation type `'e'` and precision `p-1` would have exponent `exp`. Then if `-4 <= exp < p`, the number is formatted with presentation type `'f'` and precision `p-1-exp`. Otherwise, the number is formatted with presentation type `'e'` and precision `p-1`. In both cases insignificant trailing zeros are removed from the significand, and the decimal point is also removed if there are no remaining digits following it, unless the `'#'` option is used.
>
> Positive and negative infinity, positive and negative zero, and nans, are formatted as `inf`, `-inf`, `0`, `-0` and `nan` respectively, regardless of the precision.
>
> A precision of `0` is treated as equivalent to a precision of `1`. The default precision is `6`.

With alternative values:

```
>>> "%.3e" % 123
'1.230e+02'
>>> "%.3g" % 123
'123'
>>> "%.3e" % 1234
'1.234e+03'
>>> "%.3g" % 1234
'1.23e+03'
```

The difference then is clearly about how the precision is specified. `g` appears to use the precision as the normal definition of precision, whereas `e` uses the number of figures *after* the decimal point.

Comment: This shows that the behaviour is intended. But why?

Comment: @steffen No idea why it was designed this way. That would almost certainly be a different question though.

Comment: @Velox How would this be a different question? I asked "Why...", not "Where is it stated?". Don't get me wrong. Thank you for you answer, it is interesting to read the actual standard.

Comment: @steffen:  The reason for Python's behavior is that it was copying C's behavior.  Not so satisfying, but that's the reason.  As to why C has them, I can only imagine that enough people needed each behavior for it to be so.

Comment: @steffen:  And it looks like C was also copying prior art.  See [The origin of sprintf-style string formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211741/the-origin-of-sprintf-style-string-formatting) and [Why was the percent sign (%) chosen as the format specifier for the printf family of functions?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159593/why-was-the-percent-sign-chosen-as-the-format-specifier-for-the-printf-famil)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski best answer so far! Please make it an answer!

Answer (score 3):

From the [`printf(3)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> e, E
>
> The double argument is rounded and converted in the style [-]d.ddde±dd where there is one digit before the decimal-point character and **the number of digits after it is equal to the precision**; if the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is zero, no decimal-point character appears. An E conversion uses the letter E (rather than e) to introduce the exponent. The exponent always contains at least two digits; if the value is zero, the exponent is 00.
>
> ...
>
> g, G
>
> The double argument is converted in style f or e (or F or E for G conversions). **The precision specifies the number of significant digits.** If the precision is missing, 6 digits are given; if the precision is zero, it is treated as 1. Style e is used if the exponent from its conversion is less than -4 or greater than or equal to the precision. Trailing zeros are removed from the fractional part of the result; a decimal point appears only if it is followed by at least one digit.

So, they do different things even with the same precision.

Comment: This shows that the behaviour is intended. But why?

Comment: ... You want me to tell you why BCPL's designers did what they did? Sorry, not psychic.

Comment: Yes, my question was why. I thought maybe there is an obvious advantage, that I don't see...

Answer (score 1):

I will try to describe the rules for `%g` first.

I found @Dale Myers 's quoted docs very much tells the details already, I suggest take a look at it, but I will give a more clear explanation here.

### Exponent and Precision

Before we start talking about the rules, let's make it clear the meaning for the words `exp` (the Exponent used in the scientific notation) and `precision` (will be shorted as `p`, it is the precision used in the formatting expression, `%.6e` or `%.6g`. Precision is default to 6).

### Rules for general format

OK, here goes the rules for `%g` (general format):

- `-4 <= exp < p`: use the decimal format
- `exp < -4`: use the exponential format
- `exp >= p`: use the exponential format
- the result will be rounded when calculating the precision digits.
- the precision is used to restrict all digits not just for decimal digits.

Let's see all the edge cases below:

```
>>> gx = '%.6g'
>>> ex = '%.6e'
# -4 <= exp < p
>>> gx % 12345
12345
>>> gx % 0.012345
0.012345
# exp == p
>>> ex % 1234567
1.23456e+06
>>> gx % 1234567
1.23457e+06 # Notic the decimal digits are rounded
# exp == -4
>>> ex % 0.000123456
1.234560e-4
>>> gx % 0.000123456
0.000123456
# exp < -4
>>> ex % 0.0000123456
1.234560e-5
>>> gx % 0.0000123456
1.23456e-5
```

### Why we need `%g`

If you now understand the rules for `%g`, it is quite clear that it tries to find a middle ground between `%f` and `e`, so that when formatting numbers, it will use the most appropriate format for you instead of deciding `%f` or `%e` by yourself.